# How to get first Character of every underscore delimiter using bash

Tags: bash, text-processing, cut

Hi Team there is a scenario where table name such as

```
head_must_report

customer_report_sub_division

country_code_universe_nation_part
```

However using cut command output should be as below. Note: table name would be underscore delimiter.

```
HMR

CRSD

CCUNP
```

using bash script

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Please use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format your input as code. Also, pelase [edit] your question and give us some details. You say you have a table, is it a database? Or is each of these a line in a file? Or maybe is each of these a variable? What operating system are you using?

Comment: sorry your correct

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski any input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
perl -ple 's/(?:^|_)(.)[^_]*/\U$1/g'
```

This Perl command reads lines from standard input and converts them according to the rules that you mentioned in the question.  It does this using a substitution command (`s///`) which extracts and up-cases each character that occurs either at the start of the string or directly after an underscore character.  The variant above matches *any* character at those locations in the string, but you may want to restrict this by changing `(.)` to `([a-z])` to only match lower-case letters.

Example:

```bsh
$ echo yeah_seem_to_work | perl -ple 's/(?:^|_)(.)[^_]*/\U$1/g'
YSTW
```

Answer (score 3):

Without Perl, just using `sed` and `tr`:

```
> sed 's/\(.\)[^_]*_*/\1/g' /tmp/data | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'
HMR

CRSD

CCUNP
```

Comment: +1. But why not to use `y` command inside `sed` instead of `tr`? Like : `s/\(.\)[^_]*_*/\1/g;y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/'`

Answer (score 1):

`perl` with no use of regex:

```
perl -lne 'print map {/./;uc $&} split /_/' test
```

---

`Gnu sed`  with the use of `\u` :

```
sed 's/_*\(.\)[^_]*/\u\1/g' test
```

---

`Posix sed` :

```
sed 's/_*\(.\)[^_]*/\1/g;y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/' test
```

---

`Posix awk` (tested with `Gnu awk`, `mawk` and `busybox awk`) :

```
awk -F_ -v OFS="" '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i = toupper(substr($i, 1, 1))}1' test
```

---

`python` (2 or 3):

```py
python -c '
import sys
print("".join([k[0].capitalize() for k in sys.argv[1].split("_")]))
' string
```

Answer (score 0):

And for Snowflake it is

```
regexp_replace(table_name, '\(.\)\([^_]*_*\)', '\\1')
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please use code formatting tools so that your regex isn't interpreted as markdown.